# Show that a function is Lipschitz-continuous.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have a non-linear system of ODE's (IVP) on the form

$$x'=f(t,x(t)),\quad x(\tau)=\xi,$$

where

$$f(t,x(t))=\begin{bmatrix}f_1(t,x_1(t)) \\ f_2(t,x_2(t))\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}r_1x_1(t)\left(1-\frac{x_1(t)}{K_1}\right)-\alpha_1x_1(t)x_2(t) \\
    r_2x_2(t)\left(1-\frac{x_2(t)}{K_2}\right)-\alpha_2x_2(t)x_1(t)\end{bmatrix}.$$
I would like to show that this $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous with a Lipschitz constant $L$. My first attempt was to directly use the definition of Lipschitz-continuous on both $f_1$ and $f_2$ separately, like this

$$||f_1(t,x)-f_1(t,y)||=\left\Vert\color{red}{\left(r_1\left(1-\frac{x}{K_1}\right)-\alpha_2x_2\right)}\right\Vert||(x-y)||$$

However the red part above is not a constant. How do I do this?

Comment: It is not Lipschitz, so you can't. The function $f(0,(x,0)) = r_1 x(1-{x \over K_1})$ is not Lipschitz.

Comment: Okay, I have 3 questions: 1) How can you show that it is not? 2) If it is not, can one still use Picard Lindelöf to show that there exists only positive unique solutions given positive starting values $\xi?$ 3) Isn't $f$ a $C^1-$function? Because if it is, then any $C^1$ function is locally Lipschitz in every point in its domain.

Comment: There is no $L$ such that $|f(0,(x,0))-f(0,(y,0))| \le L|x-y|$ for all $x,y$. This is straightforward to show either by contradiction or using derivatives. Yes it is smooth and so is locally Lipschitz continuous everywhere. 2) is not a question that can be answered in comments.